# Gem for region to country: Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, country

is there a `gem` whose input will be a region and out country of that region.
e.g if i give `bay area` => `United Stats`, `Pune` => `India`, `greater minneapolis-st. paul area`=> `United States`. I just want to know wether given region exits in US or Canada

Answer (score 0):

You might have some luck with the [Carmen](https://github.com/jim/carmen) gem.